# determinant of block matrix equal to 1

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

I need to prove that

$$
\det \begin{pmatrix}
I & A\\
0 & I
\end{pmatrix} =1.
$$

I have tried deriving this from other known block matrices such as
$
\begin{pmatrix}
I & 0\\
0 & D
\end{pmatrix} = \det(D)
$
and
$\begin{pmatrix}
A & 0\\
0 & D
\end{pmatrix} = \det(A) \det(D)
$

but got stuck.  Could anyone give me hints of how to proceed?

Comment: Have you tried using the [Expansion by Minors](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DeterminantExpansionbyMinors.html) and an induction ?

Comment: This is an upper triangular matrix which is known to have determinant given by the product of its leading diagonal.

Comment: thank you! It makes sense

Comment: Hint: how many permutations $\sigma$ of $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ are there, such that $\sigma(i)\le i$ for all $i$? (see the [Leibniz formula for determinants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_determinants))

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to find the determinant. Here are two suggestions:

- Your matrix is upper triangular
- You can reduce away $A$ with elementary row operations